# I did [chown -r root /usr/share/applications] when i just intended to only chown

Tags: permissions, chown

I did an similar mistake back then [chown -r the whole /usr folder], and had to reinstall ubuntu and its apps (which is painful for me, mostly because i'm not used to the SO)

I just wanna know if it is possible to have any major issue, mainly with those apps, or root ,in the end, does already handle with their execution, and this own change.

Thx owo

(Edit 001: Forgot the "/" before usr in the path in the title)
(Edit 002: I did everything in sudo, forgot to mention that (else i wouldn't have been able to do that mistake I guess)
(Edit 003: I just got home, and looked up through the terminal commands.  Ended up that i did `sudo chown -r root /usr/share`)

Comment: Looks like everything in `/usr/share/applications` is owned by root so I think you will be OK.

Comment: is the missing / before usr/ a mistake or is that the actual command used? :)

Comment: The command should have done nothing (and indeed returned an error) for two reasons: 1) That path does not exist - all paths start with root (/). 2) You didn't use sudo. Advice: Slow down, so you make fewer easy typos. Avoid using the root account - use sudo properly. When doing anything outside your /home. *look twice* and check flags and paths before hitting <enter>. Get into safer *habits* that prevent you from destroying your system again.

Comment: @Terrance thx, i did think that, but wasn't sure
@Rinzwind Just a mistake haha. The wrong command that i did was `sudo chown -r root /usr/share`

Comment: @user535733 Thx for the advices. I do not have anything important in this ubuntu installation (it's a 200gb that i partitioned from my windows notebook, to try new stuff and learn how to use linux. I did expect to make a lot of mistakes) I'm a _lot_ used to use GUIs, for almost everything, that does involve file management. (mainly i stuck with trying to move things to root owned folders, as fonts, by example, and i just know to chown to me the folder rights, and then chown back.

Answer (score 7):

```
/usr/share/applications
```

The permissions for -all- files in there is:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root
```

So ...

```
chown root:root /usr/share/applications/
chmod 644 /usr/share/applications/
```

will restore it to default (I added both command just in case someone else ends up here looking for it but all you need is the chmod).

There are no directories in /usr/share/applications/ so the -r did nothing in your case.

Comment: I was trying to manualy install an Application (I had the package, but didn't have internet connection at the moment to search), then I did the following:
 
`sudo chown kuuh_lts /usr/share/`,
**Then i moved the folder to /usr/share**,
`sudo chown -R root /usr/share/SoundWireServer`, 
_I thought that i had to give root the ownership of all the app files_.
Then i had to chown back to root /usr/share/applications, then i changed the last command line that i used, but forgot to remove the recursive mode (-R). 
So i ended up doing 
`sudo chown -r root /usr/share/`.

Comment: I'll try chmod 644 if I notice any issue in the next day. Thanks for the help!